# ios - uiimage array to video image orientation and scale

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a video from an array of uiimage.

I've used multiple stackoverflow posts and mixed and modified a lot of the provided code.

I will include the file that I'm currently using.

The images are currently coming out like this and I'm thinking it's because since they are turned into CGImage, they don't retain orientation?

Also, how do I handle the scaling for when a user takes a horizontal picture.

I basically want to show the images as they were taken.

The first two images were taken vertically and look flipped 90 degrees to the left and the last horizontally.

Thank you
[image]

[image]

[image]

Class:

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

let kErrorDomain = "TimeLapseBuilder"
let kFailedToStartAssetWriterError = 0
let kFailedToAppendPixelBufferError = 1

public class TimeLapseBuilder: NSObject {
  var photos: [UIImage]
  var videoWriter: AVAssetWriter?
  var outputSize = CGSizeMake(1920, 1080)

  public init(photos: [UIImage]) {
    self.photos = photos

    super.init()
  }

  public func build(outputSize outputSize: CGSize, progress: (NSProgress -> Void), success: (NSURL -> Void), failure: (NSError -> Void)) {

    self.outputSize = outputSize
    var error: NSError?

    let startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    guard let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first else {
      fatalError("documentDir Error")
    }

    let videoOutputURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("AssembledVideo.mov")

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(videoOutputURL.path!) {
      do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(videoOutputURL.path!)
      }catch{
        fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(__FUNCTION__).")
      }
    }

    guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: videoOutputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie) else{
      fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
    }

    let outputSettings = [
      AVVideoCodecKey  : AVVideoCodecH264,
      AVVideoWidthKey  : NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.width)),
      AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.height)),
    ]

    guard videoWriter.canApplyOutputSettings(outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
      fatalError("Negative : Can't apply the Output settings...")
    }

    let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)

    let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [
      kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
      kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.width)),
      kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(outputSize.height)),
    ]

    let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
      assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
      sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary
    )

    assert(videoWriter.canAddInput(videoWriterInput))
    videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)

    if videoWriter.startWriting() {
      videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
      assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)

      let media_queue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", nil)

      videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(media_queue, usingBlock: { () -> Void in
        let fps: Int32 = 1
        let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, fps)
        let currentProgress = NSProgress(totalUnitCount: Int64(self.photos.count))

        var frameCount: Int64 = 0

        while (!self.photos.isEmpty) {


          if (videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
            let nextPhoto = self.photos.removeAtIndex(0)
            let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount, fps)
            let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)



            if !self.appendPixelBufferForImage(nextPhoto, pixelBufferAdaptor: pixelBufferAdaptor, presentationTime: presentationTime) {
              error = NSError(domain: kErrorDomain, code: kFailedToAppendPixelBufferError,
                userInfo: [
                  "description": "AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter failed to append pixel buffer",
                  "rawError": videoWriter.error ?? "(none)"
                ])

              break
            }

            frameCount++

            currentProgress.completedUnitCount = frameCount
            progress(currentProgress)
          }
        }

        let endTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        let elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = endTime - startTime

        print("rendering time \(self.stringFromTimeInterval(elapsedTime))")


        videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
        videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
          if error == nil {
            success(videoOutputURL)
          }
        }
      })


    } else {
      error = NSError(domain: kErrorDomain, code: kFailedToStartAssetWriterError,
        userInfo: ["description": "AVAssetWriter failed to start writing"]
      )
    }

    if let error = error {
      failure(error)
    }
  }

  public func appendPixelBufferForImage(image: UIImage, pixelBufferAdaptor: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, presentationTime: CMTime) -> Bool {
    var appendSucceeded = true

    autoreleasepool {

        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
        let options: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : Int(true),
            kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : Int(true)
        ]

        let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options as CFDictionaryRef, &pixelBuffer)

        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer where status == 0 {
          let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer

            print("Scaleeee \(image.scale)")
            print("Widthhhh \(image.size.width)")
            print("Heighttt \(image.size.height)")


            pixelBufferFromImage(image.CGImage!, pxbuffer: managedPixelBuffer, andSize: CGSize(width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

          appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)

        } else {
          NSLog("error: Failed to allocate pixel buffer from pool")
        }

    }

    return appendSucceeded
  }

    func pixelBufferFromImage(image: CGImageRef, pxbuffer: CVPixelBuffer, andSize size: CGSize){

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0)
        let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer)
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, Int(size.width), Int(size.height), 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer), rgbColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0))

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), image)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0)
    }

//    //Old fillpixel method
//  func fillPixelBufferFromImage(image: UIImage, pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, contentMode:UIViewContentMode){
//
//    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
////    
//    let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)
//    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
//    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, Int(self.outputSize.width), Int(self.outputSize.height), 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer), rgbColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
//
//    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(self.outputSize.width), CGFloat(self.outputSize.height)))
//    
//    let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / image.size.width
//    let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / image.size.height
//    var ratio: CGFloat = 1
//    
////    print("horizontal ratio \(horizontalRatio)")
////    print("vertical ratio \(verticalRatio)")
////    print("ratio \(ratio)")
////    print("Image Width -  \(image.size.width). Image Height - \(image.size.height)")
//    
//    switch(contentMode) {
//    case .ScaleAspectFill:
//      ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
//    case .ScaleAspectFit:
//      ratio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
//    default:
//      ratio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
//    }
//    
//    let newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * ratio, image.size.height * ratio)
//    
//    let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
//    let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0
//
//    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(x, y, newSize.width, newSize.height), image.CGImage)
//
//    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)
//  }


  func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    let ti = NSInteger(interval)
    let ms = Int((interval % 1) * 1000)
    let seconds = ti % 60
    let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours = (ti / 3600)

    if hours > 0 {
      return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d.%0.2d", hours, minutes, seconds, ms) as String
    }else if minutes > 0 {
      return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d.%0.2d", minutes, seconds, ms) as String
    }else {
      return NSString(format: "%0.2d.%0.2d", seconds, ms) as String
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with UIImage, as the orientation is usually derived from the EXIF data on the camera.

I have written an extension on UIImage that allows me to access an instance of the image in the correct orientation.

```
extension UIImage {
    var fixedOrientation: UIImage {
        if self.imageOrientation == .Up {
            return self
        }

        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case .Down:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.width)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
            break
        case .DownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.width)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
            break
        case .Left:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            break
        case .LeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            break
        case .Right:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            break
        case .RightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
            break
        case .Up:
            break
        case .UpMirrored:
            break
        }

        switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case .UpMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
            break;
        case .DownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
            break;
        case .LeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
            break
        case .RightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
            break
        case .Up:
            break
        case .Right:
            break
        case .Down:
            break
        case .Left:
            break
        }

        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(self.size.width), Int(self.size.height), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0, CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage), CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue)
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform)

        switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case .Left:
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height, self.size.width), self.CGImage)
            break
        case .LeftMirrored:
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height, self.size.width), self.CGImage)
            break
        case .Right:
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height, self.size.width), self.CGImage)
            break
        case .RightMirrored:
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.height, self.size.width), self.CGImage)
            break
        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), self.CGImage)
            break
        }

        let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
        let uiImage = UIImage.init(CGImage: cgImage!)

        return uiImage
    }
}
```

Similarly, if you know the desired `CGSize` you want your image to be (you can usually get away with using the current view's bounds) then you can use this as an extension of UIImage as well.

```
extension UIImage {
    func resize(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        self.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

I am also curious to see if this can be refactored, but this always does the trick for me - hope this helps!

Comment: dokun, considering I'm grabbing the images from coredata and storing them in an array of uiimages and also that the video is created using the cgimage property of the uiimage, can you please give me some guidance on the implementation with this extension? Thanks for your help man

Comment: Hi @Walking, if you write this as it's own class as an extension, you'll be able to use it as if the functions/vars were members of the class already. When you have the array of `UIImage` objects, if you were to use the extension I wrote, you would want to get the `fixOrientation` var on each of them to get the corrected version. It also occurs to me that this would be better written as a function that returns `UIImage` instead of a var on it, so I would iterate over the array and store all of the corrected images. The `CGImage` var on each of them should be corrected as well.